# C# IDisposable Using: Best Practice

Tags: c#, coding-style, idisposable, using

I have been wrapping my OracleConnection and OracleCommand objects in USING statements for a while now, however, after running code analyzer I discover that OracleParameter also implements IDisposable.  Is the following code correct?  Is there a better technique for readability or structure?  At first glance it just seems to be cluttered with USING statements:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionstring))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.BindByName = true;

        using (OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter("p1", OracleDbType.Int32, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input))
        {
            param1.Value = int.Parse(value1);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
        }

        using (OracleParameter param2 = new OracleParameter("p2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input))
        {
            param2.Value = value2;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
        }

        using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // loop data here...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to dispose of the parameters only at the very end of their use, including during the query (and possibly the reading of the results):

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionstring))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.BindByName = true;

        using (OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter("p1", OracleDbType.Int32, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input))
        using (OracleParameter param2 = new OracleParameter("p2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input))
        {
            param1.Value = int.Parse(value1);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
            param2.Value = value2;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

            using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // loop data here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you can put multiple `using` statements in a row. This is because, like the `if` statement,

1. A `using` statement is considered a simple statement (even with a block); and
2. A `using` statement can take either a block or a statement underneath.

Comment: Although there were many similar answers, I appreciated that you provided both examples and commentary.

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could be of help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionstring)) 
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn)) 
using (OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter("p1", OracleDbType.Int32,
       System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input)) 
using (OracleParameter param2 = new OracleParameter("p2", OracleDbType.Varchar2,
       System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input)) 
}
    conn.Open(); 
    cmd.BindByName = true; 

    param1.Value = int.Parse(value1); 
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param1); 

    param2.Value = value2; 
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param2); 

    using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    { 
        // loop data here... 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that will work properly.  Consider that at the end of the using, both parameters should have been disposed.  The fact that your `cmd.Parameters` object is still holding a reference to them does not preclude what may be happening in the `OracleParameter` Dispose method.  For all intensive purposes, the developer of that particular object may be clearing fields that your `OracleCommand` is expecting to be filled.

There's some danger there.  If you're absolutely certain you want to dispose your `OracleParameters` properly, I suggest you dispose of them after the `OracleDataReader` using.

Remember that generally you call `Dispose` when you're done using the object.  You're telling it to release all resources it's holding back to the pool.  If you're not done using an object, don't dispose of it prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

can you look at the connection and command source code, does it dispose the parameters? if the connection or command objects dispose pattern wraps the parameters and dispose them upon they are disposed. you should worry about it. which i think it would/should.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx), you only need to use `using` for `Connection` and `DataReader` objects. I have never seen `using` (or `.Dispose()`) used with ADO.NET parameter objects. If this were necessary or even desirable, I think it would have come up already some time within the last 10 years.

Comment: MSDN is talking about objects provided by the BCL.  Oracle's implemenation of these may very well require Disposing of the parameters.  Why would they implement IDisposable if they weren't intended to be Disposed?

Comment: Or they very well may not. I have never seen any ADO.NET code (for Oracle's implementation or anybody else's) that either called Dispose() on a parameter object or put it in a `using` block. Again, if disposing parameters were necessary, this would have reared its head a long time ago.

Comment: So your advice is, even though an object implements IDisposble, don't dispose it unless it's known to be a problem?  Sounds like bad advice to me.

Comment: Could easily go the better-safe-than-sorry route and dispose, but I genuinely think Oracle screwed this one up and that their dispose method probably doesn't do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not correct because you are disposing the parameters even before you use them.

Instead you should so it like this

```
OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter("p1", OracleDbType.Int32, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);

param1.Value = int.Parse(value1);
cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);


OracleParameter param2 = new OracleParameter("p2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);

param2.Value = value2;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);


using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  // loop data here...
}

param1.dispose();
param2.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is incorrect. the params you create they are still used outside the `using` statement scope because you add them to the parameter collection, but the `using` statement will call `Dispose` on the parameters upon control leaving the scope. Which means that when the time will come to use the parameters inside the command theya will have been disoised of already